# Can an indexed view on SQL Server be updated asynchronously?

Tags: sql-server, view, indexed-view

Can I create an indexed view on SQL Server that be updated asynchronously from physical table, so that the INSERT/DELETE performance will not be affected much?

Comment: No there is no such option. Performance shouldn't be that much worse than an extra index though, unless you have complex joins. One option is to just make a table that you peridiodically merge updates into, using a SQL Agent job.

Comment: All (most?) of the limitations imposed on you in being able to create indexed views are there *so that* the update activity is "cheap" - i.e. it can work based on just the rows in the table that have been changed, not needing to scan any/all of the unchanged rows, for example.

Comment: The calculation of the delta might be quite cheap but blocking can be an issue as multiple transactions might need to update the same aggregated value

Comment: Thank all for your comments. The view mapping is just some kind of open a large json into some primitive columns. So I assume that this operator is not that expensive.

Comment: Using your expensive SQL Server cores to decompose JSON coming from your application which could also do that decomposition and persist it in columns in the database is certainly a choice.